# Is it possible to transform the data that ends up in page-data.json in Gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

We have a few pages on [our Gatsby site](https://climatescape.org/) which have really large `page-data.json` files as a result of our GraphQL queries. In our component we end up transforming this data into a much more compact representation. Is it possible to tell Gatsby to store *this* data in the `page-data.json` file instead of the raw GraphQL results?

Comment: The data is what you query, so why are you querying data which you do not use?

Comment: probably you're looking for a place to conversion in the middle - f.e. like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238793/6124657 - `onPostBootstrap`

Comment: @AlbertSkibinski GraphQL has limitations in how we can structure the response such that we end up with a lot of redundancy. Or business logic that takes in 4 or 5 objects of which we end up picking one to display.